# ElasticSearch pagination on multiple indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm wondering if elasticsearch can paginate on a single multiple index query.

What I am trying to do is:

I have 2 indexes: tweets and users.

I want to do a search like this

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/foo/tweets,users"
```

and want to paginate each index, say I want 3 tweets (from 0) and 2 users (from 0).

Do you know if this is posible? maybe I have to change my structure, but I still cant think how to do this with a single call.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an [msearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)-request where you a search on `tweets` with `size` 3 and a search on `users` with a `size` of 2.